# Android Google Play Location Services continue after leaving app

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-location

I am using `Google Play Services` in my app so that I can make use of the `Location` features. I have read the docs, but it isn't clear what happens when I am running location updates and I leave the app.

**Do location updates still occur in the background? If not, how do I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do location updates still occur in the background? If not, how do I do this?

What I did for my app was to continue to track the location with a service in the background. In addition, you may want to start and mark the service as Foreground so that user will be shown a notification that you are tracking the phone's location.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate on how to mark the service as Foreground so that it shows a notification the it is tracking location?

Comment: Also, slightly confused about how to make a `Service` and update that in the background.

Comment: To mark as foreground simply use startForeground(R.string.app_name, aNotification) in onCreate.

Comment: As for services, you should read Android's guide on it if you are new to it. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove the `LocationListener` when you leave your app, usually I put it in `onPause()` method of the `Activity`, otherwise, it's up to you to handle whether you should do it. Here is the example code:

```
@Override   
protected void onPause() {      
locationMananger.removeUpdates(this);       
// with "this" is your Activity implementing the LocationListener       
super.onPause();    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, so, since my app is meant to continue location updates when the app is left, I just don't need to do anything?

Comment: You should consider develop your `Service` to run in background with a separated process and update your location. Here is the place to start with `Service`: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html . Hope this helps.